# Discrete Mathematics Proof by Case Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

If x, y are real numbers with |x+3|=4 and |y-2|=1, then x+y<10.

Case 1- Suppose x, y are R+
|x+3|=4= 1
|y-2|=1= 3 or 1
I plugged them in and in all instances they are less than 10.

Case 2 - Supposed x is R- and y is R+ (y cannot be R- ever in this case right?)
|x+3|=4=-7
|y-2|=1= 3 or 1
I plugged them in and in all instances they are less than 10.

Am I even close to getting this correct??

Answer (score 1):

Find the solutions of the equations separately.
The first equation
$$\left| x + 3 \right| = 4$$
has the solutions $x = 1$ and $x = -7$ (you know why?).
The second equation
$$\left| y - 2 \right| = 1$$
has the solutions $y = 1$ and $y = 3$.

Now calculate the four possible values of $x + y$ and conclude that they are all less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this without cases.

$$\lvert x+3\rvert=4\implies x+3=4\text{ or }x+3=-4\implies x=1\text{ or }x=-7$$

Likewise, $$\lvert y-2\rvert = 1\implies y=3\text{ or }y=1$$

Now, $x+y\le\text{ max(x) }+\text{ max(y) }\le 4\lt 10$